# Can a Windows 7 Machine be configured to act as a Router or NAT like a Linux machine can?

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, router, nat

Or should one install special software on a Windows to be able to do those things ?

I was surprised to see that a Linux machine basically can be configured to act as a Router and has many advanced capabilities such as Network Address Translating and other features. I wonder if Windows machine can do the same.

Comment: Yes;  A Windows machine can be turned into a DHCP server.

Comment: @Ramhound  However are other advanced features available such as Routing or NATing or Port Forwarding ?

Comment: There is third-party to provide that functionality.  If software for Linux can be written to perform those tasks, then software for Windows, can be written to perform those tasks.

Comment: Google "Internet Connection Sharing".